# How do I verify if JSON data satisfy a JSON Schema specification?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have JSON data in a file called `B.json` and another file with a JSON schema called `BSchema.json`.

I'd like to know how to verify if the JSON data satisfy the JSON Schema specification, for example, in Ubuntu and Windows I can use the `xmllint` program from the command line to verify the same using the following command: `xmllint --schema XMLSchemaFile.xsd --noout DataFile.xml`. So, is there any alternative to this command (in Linux or Windows) that allows me to **input the two files** and check if the JSON data satisfy the JSON Schema?

Note: if there is any other command like that in MacOS, please add to your answer, so the questions will be useful for users of all platforms.

Comment: Have you looked here? http://json-schema.org/implementations.html

Comment: I think what you need is under "validators".

Answer (score 9):

As of version 2.4, [jsonschema](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema) includes a command-line program to check some input json file against a schema specified in another file.

You can call it like so:

```
jsonschema -i B.json BSchema.json
```

Here's some example output from when I put an object where an array should be:

> {u'description': u'Doubles resource collection.'}: {u'description': u'Doubles resource collection.'} is not of type u'array'

Comment: Meanwhile, `jsonschema` is deprecating its cli in favor of `check-jsonschema`, which is also a public package.

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell Core there is a built-in method that allows you to do the validation `test-json`. PowerShell syntax: `Test-Json [-Json] <String> [[-Schema] <String>]`. For more information have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json

In the question it was also asked about the environments. Powershell Core v.7.0+ is cross-platform so this validation can be done anywhere. If you can't or don't want to use PowerShell you can try some Python tool like this: [Validate JSON file syntax in shell script without installing any package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385036/validate-json-file-syntax-in-shell-script-without-installing-any-package/47289898)

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of command-line tools available that will allow you to validate a json against json schema

If it is a one-time thing , you can look at [json-spec](https://github.com/johnnoone/json-spec). But I found it lacking in following references in json schema.

But if you need a CI tool and you use node.js/grunt as your dev environment, use [tv4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4) and its grunt job [grunt-tv4](https://github.com/timbeadle/grunt-tv4)

Answer (score -2):

Here is a web based tool that looks to do what you want it to: http://jsonschemalint.com/

It looks to be based off of this library: https://github.com/garycourt/JSV

I hope this helps!