# Validate JSON file syntax in shell script without installing any package

Tags: json, shell

How can I validate the syntax of a JSON file in shell script without installing any package?

Comment: have you tried `jq`?

Comment: @codeforester That's arguably a "package"... but the question is basically asking how to write a JSON parser in shell script, which is very broad.

Comment: I have written this in java and it perfectly working fine :)

Comment: validating json file again Json schema

Answer (score 47):

I have yet to find a system where `python -mjson.tool` doesn't work. So you can do:

```
python -mjson.tool "$somefile" > /dev/null
```

The exit code will be nonzero and you get the parse error on stderr if the file is not valid JSON.

Note: The Python libraries don't follow the JSON spec and allow `NaN` and `Infinity` as values. So using `json.tool` will let some errors slip through. Still it's good enough for my use case of catching errors in human-written documents early.

Comment: How can you use this to scan all .json files in a directory?

Comment: `for j in *.json; do python -mjson.tool "$j" > /dev/null || echo "INVALID $j" >&2; done;`
You can do `exit 1` instead of `echo` to just break at the first error.

Comment: The main goal of the question is "without installing any package".

Comment: @alfredo `json.tool` comes with base python therefore you don't need to install it; and python, is fairly uncommon that it doesn't come installed in most *nix. `json.tool` works well too: it doesn't take `{}` or `5` as valid json; you have to pass in real `json` to succeed

Comment: Is the output to /dev/null necessary? Seems kind of superfluous for well-designed software that should just display output when redirecation isn't specified.

Comment: @default123 `json.tool` will output the pretty printed JSON it received. Because we're not interested in the output, we have to drop it. When the question is "without installing any package", you might be looking at a hacky answer :-)

Answer (score 23):

The very simplest way is using json_pp (json pretty print)

```
$ echo {} | json_pp
{}
```

```
$ echo [] | json_pp
[]
```

```
$ echo 5 | json_pp
5
```

```
$ echo a | json_pp
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "a\n") at /usr/bin/json_pp line 59.
```

For file you can do

```
$ cat file.json | json_pp
```

For more info

```
$ man json_pp
```

Comment: This answer treat the goal of the question: "without installing any package".

Comment: This is pretty (pun intended) cool! 
Unlike the other validators, this actually prints the JSON, and gives a better sense of completeness.

Comment: if we get nothing from json_pp function that means it's valid right?

Comment: No, if it returns the JSON data it means valid, otherwise it returns an error containing malformed.    

cat your.json | json_pp | grep malformed 

is what you are searching for. nothing = valid, otherwise it returns an output

Answer (score 9):

Usually `python` is installed on the system, so you can use it to parse JSON.

```
cat YOURFILENAME | python -c "import sys,json;json.loads(sys.stdin.read());print 'OK'"
```

I will print "OK" if the schema is valid.

Examples:

1.

```
$ echo {} | python -c "import sys,json;json.loads(sys.stdin.read());print 'OK'"
OK
```

2.

```
$ echo [] | python -c "import sys,json;json.loads(sys.stdin.read());print 'OK'"
OK
```

3.

```
$ echo 5 | python -c "import sys,json;json.loads(sys.stdin.read());print 'OK'"
OK
```

4.

```
$echo a | python -c "import sys,json;json.loads(sys.stdin.read());print 'OK'"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: To add this in a git `pre-commit` or `pre-push` hook such that any invalid JSON in the repository causes a non-zero exit code: `find . -type f -name "*.json" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'cat $0 | py -c "import sys,json;json.loads(sys.stdin.read())" || (echo "INVALID JSON: $0" && echo && exit 1)'` or avoiding the stack trace: `find . -type f -name "*.json" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'cat $0 | py -c "import sys,json; exec(\"try:json.loads(sys.stdin.read())\nexcept Exception as e:print(e); sys.exit(1)\")" || (echo "INVALID JSON: $0" && echo && exit 1)'`

Answer (score 4):

I   had  multiple  json strings  concatenated in one file, and  multiple  files  of this  type in same  folder.  Bellow  code will  compose a list  of  files  to validate, read  each file  line by  line  and  validate  json string in each  line.  If  an  invalid line is found then  break loop  and  notify user  which  file  has  invalid  json, line number, line content failed  validation. This  code  is especially useful  when  json fields  contain  HTML  escaped  content and  we  have to make  sure  it  is  not  breaking json integrity.

```
for filename in *txt; do
lncnt=0 
echo $filename
while read  -r  line; do        
    lncnt=$((lncnt+1))      
    echo "${line}" | python -m json.tool 
    RET=$?
    if  [ $RET -gt 0 ] ; then
      echo "Error in $filename:$lncnt ${line}" 
      break
    fi
  done < $filename
done
```

Example file content:

```
cat file1.txt
{"key11":"Value1","key12":"value2"}
{"key21":"Value1","key22":"value2"}
{"key31":"Value1","key32":"value2"}
{"key41":"Value1","key42":"value2"}
{"key41":"INVALID_CLOSED,"key42":"value2"}
{"key51":"Value1","key52":"value2"}
```

Expected  result:

```
file1.txt
{
    "key11": "Value1",
    "key12": "value2"
}
{
    "key21": "Value1",
    "key22": "value2"
}
{
    "key31": "Value1",
    "key32": "value2"
}
{
    "key41": "Value1",
    "key42": "value2"
}
Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 26 (char 26)
Error in file1.txt:5 {"key41":"INVALID_CLOSED,"key42":"value2"}
```

Eventually, during validation you will not  want to see  valid  jsons  printed, just eroneous ones. To  achieve  that you can  redirect json tool  output  to /dev/null

```
 echo "${line}" | python -m json.tool
```

to

```
echo "${line}" | python -m json.tool > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell Core (cross-platform) there is a built-in method that allows you to do the validation `test-json`. PowerShell syntax: `Test-Json [-Json] <String> [[-Schema] <String>]`. For more information have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somehow (curl?) push json to https://search.google.com/test/rich-results
See API options here: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools

Or:

Requires jq (parallel is optional, could use xargs):

```
[pjalajas@sup-pjalajas-2 504Project]$ find test_0009 -iname "*.jsonld" | parallel "jq '.' 2> /dev/null ; echo $?" | cut -d\  -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1nr

1660 0
```