# How to fix function which I'm trying to pass into "payload" in bash ? I've stuck with error "invalid payload"

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, slack-api

I'm trying to configure custom slack notification from GitLab but keep getting error **"invalid payload"** in GitlabCI. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong? Maybe that's an error in my function? Btw I've tested the weebhook itself and it's valid and working as expected

This is a piece from my .gitlab-ci-.yaml

```
  ENVIRONMENT_NAME: "staging"
  extends: .Deploy_image
  only:
    - master
  after_script:
    - if [ ${CI_JOB_STATUS} == "success" ]; then EXIT_STATUS=0; else EXIT_STATUS=1; fi
    - envsubst </tmp/${CI_PIPELINE_ID}/${SCRIPT_PATH}/slackscript.sh> "slackscript.sh"
    - source ./slackscript.sh; share_slack_update_deploy
```

and the script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

FAILURE=1
SUCCESS=0
SLACKWEBHOOKURL="my webhook url"

function print_slack_summary_deploy() {

    local slack_msg_header
    local slack_msg_body
    local slack_channel
# Populate header and define slack channels
slack_msg_header=":x: *Deploy to ${ENVIRONMENT_NAME} failed*"
if [[ "${EXIT_STATUS}" == "${SUCCESS}" ]]; then
        slack_msg_header=":heavy_check_mark: *Deploy to ${ENVIRONMENT_NAME} succeeded*"
        slack_channel="channel-name"
    fi
cat <<-SLACK
            {
                "blocks": [
                    {
                        "type": "section",
                        "text": {
                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                            "text": "${slack_msg_header}"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "divider"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "section",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "type": "mrkdwn",
                                "text": "*Stage:*\nDeploy"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "mrkdwn",
                                "text": "*Pushed By:*\n${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "mrkdwn",
                                "text": "*Job URL:*\nGITLAB_REPO_URL/${CI_JOB_ID}"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "mrkdwn",
                                "text": "*Commit Message:*\nGITLAB_REPO_URL/${CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE}"
                            {
                                "type": "mrkdwn",
                                "text": "*Commit URL:*\nGITLAB_REPO_URL$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "mrkdwn",
                                "text": "*Commit Branch:*\n${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "divider"
                    }
                ]
}
SLACK
}

function share_slack_update_deploy() {

local slack_webhook

slack_webhook="$SLACKWEBHOOKURL"

curl -X POST                                           \
        --data-urlencode "payload=$(print_slack_summary_deploy)"  \
        "${slack_webhook}"
}
```

Comment: It turns out that I have an error in my JSON format. I'd advise everyone to check their syntax in some json validator

Answer (score 0):

> I've tested the webhook itself and it's valid and working as expected

If the webhook works locally (meaning the `curl` to `${slack_webhook}` is successful), but the same webhook, when called by GitLab CI, does not work, that should probably mean one of the variables used in `print_slack_summary_deploy()` is not correctly valued (or is empty), resulting in an invalid payload.

I would display those variables in a debug print, and compare them with the one done during a manual (successful) test done locally.

---

As noted by the [OP Vlad Tkachuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15541195/vlad-tkachuk), the root cause was the JSON being invalid.

A tool like [`/usr/bin/json_pp`](https://metacpan.org/dist/JSON-PP/view/bin/json_pp) (usually present when Perl is already installed) can help validate the variable ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69323172/6309))

```
echo "${myJSONvar}" | json_pp 2>/dev/null || exit -1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Fortunately I've managed to fix this

Comment: @VladTkachuk Great, well done! I have included your conclusion in the answer, as well as a link to help others validate their own JSON string in their bash script.